# Is a package a hybrid when its ex, Version 2.0.0 Really 1.8.2?

Tags: package-management, packaging

I knew these packages exists, I've seen them everyware but I never understood them. I'm not sure if they have features from the generic X.X.X (Aka Version X.X.X) or if Its just Really X.X.X and the Version number is a lie as when you install one of these in Ubuntu they appear with the "Really" number not the Version number. Also it could be all the features in the "Version" ported to a older version (Really) and is a hybrid. I mean like here[1] they decided to go with an older version of banshee that's based on GTK 2.XX (for Trusty) but in my hypothesis this "Hybrid/Really" would be the GTK 2.XX based version (2.6.1) but with features from the GTK 3.XX Based version (2.9.1). So is my hypothesis correct or no? I'm just trying to understand these weird Releases

[1]https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/banshee

Also see:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/banshee/2.6.1-2ubuntu1
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/banshee/2.9.0-2ubuntu1
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/banshee/2.9.0+really2.6.1-0ubuntu1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the changelog entry for the specific version you're talking about it explains why they had to upload with `+really2.6.1`:

```
banshee (2.9.0+really2.6.1-0ubuntu1) trusty; urgency=low

  * [fbf05ca] Imported Upstream version 2.9.0+really2.6.1:  <---
    Downgrade to 2.6.1 -- 2.9.x is unstable and 3.0 won't arrive in time for
    release
  * [22de440] Revert packaging to 2.6.1-2ubuntu1
  * [7357b73] Merge changes from 2.6.1-5
  * [a7156c0] Filter out libgpod-cil-dev versions built against gtk#3
  * [e7c634d] Update dversionmangle for extracting +really version out
 -- Chow Loong Jin <hyperair@debian.org>   Sun, 09 Feb 2014 23:06:03 +0800
```

The problem with apt repositories is that once a version that is uploaded that supersedes the older version number, you can't easily get `apt` and `dpkg` to take the old version number and bump it back upwards.  Because they reverted to 2.6.1 and can't revert the version number *truly* to 2.6.1 because Trusty will start to complain, they had to do it this way.

This does not mean it's a hybrid package.  They just reverted everything back to 2.6.1 and merged some changes from Debian 2.6.1-5 into this version.  They had to add the `+really2.6.1` so that apt would see this as a higher version than `2.9.0-2ubuntu1` on Trusty systems is all.

Comment: Ah, I see so same with the gnome-cards package in precise which is 3.4.2 really 3.2.3.2. So It the "Version" is a lie if there is a "Really" in the mix.

Comment: @davidbuddy9 I can only answer for this one package, to really understand what's going on you have to read the changelog for the package.  Basically... *there is no one true way to define these things*.